# How do I create a branch specifically for builds?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I need to set up a branch made **only** for builds.
I have a project made on JS with a server in another repo. Folder structure there is complex and there are lots of non-production files.

What I need is a separate branch with this folder structure:

```
build/   # For project build
server/  # For server build
```

How do I achieve that? I don't want to merge this branch with `master`, neither do I want to create conflicts with other branches and files inside the repo that already exist

Comment: Why do you want to create a branch? Aren't the build results temporary? What do you want to commit on this branch? Do you want to create one branch for all builds, or one per build?

Comment: It sounds like this is for a setup like [GitHub's `gh-pages` feature](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages), where the contents of a specific branch are served. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do the same as gh-pages, but to keep my build ready for deployment